# How can I make this pluck sound?

Tags: sound-design

At 00:17 you can hear the pluck, I'd like to make that.

Could someone please tell me how to make it?

I have Sylenth1 and I have some basic knowledge how ADSR works, and LFO's, but I have no idea where to begin...

I have searched on youtube for it, but didn't find any tutorial which was near that sound.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: This video is blocked in many countries (all I tried). Would you mind updating the link?

Answer (score -1):

May be Sylenth1 isn't the best synth for generating more complex sound, but for basic understanding of pluck sound quite enough.

Main point at plucked sound is a loud *click* at the beginning and scratchy long release. So, by using our lovely ADSR you can basically:

1. **Reset preset.** *Menu* => Init Preset.
2. **Filter Setup.** *Filter Type* => Low Pass, *Cutoff* = 0.
3. **Modulation Envelope Setup.** By envelope target chose *Cutoff A*, *Decay* set approx on 2,7.
4. **Most tasty part.** By adjusting *ModEnv1 destination* you can tune *click*, and by *sustain* (surprisingly) *release*.

All other settings for your experiments.

Also I've tried to make maximally similar to video sound on Sylenth1. Chek this [link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ekbeuqi6jsdvuhh/AACz3JtA3gGb4B4EwVoZCNSaa?dl=0).